# foreach error with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

Hey im using codeigniter and i got this error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: views/nyheder_view.php

Line Number: 2
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/nyheder_view.php

Line Number: 2

my controller :

```
   <?php

class Nyheder extends Controller {

 function index()
    {
  $data['content'] = 'nyheder_view';
   $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

    }

 function vis()
 {
  //parent::controller();
  $this->load->model('nyheder_model');
  $data['query'] = $this->nyheder_model->load_nyheder();

  $this->load->view('nyheder_view', $data);

 }
}
?>
```

my view

```
<?php foreach($query as $row) : ?>
<h1><?php echo $row->overskrift; ?></h1>
<p><?php echo $row->indhold; ?></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Please show us the `nyheder_model` too.

Comment: As others have suggested, your $this->nyheder_model->load_nyheder(); must be returning null or false.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything immediately wrong here. Could you put this line in just before you load your nyheader_view:

```
die(var_export($data));
```

And let us know what you see.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that $this->nyheder_model->load_nyheder() returns false or null.

try var_dump($this->nyheder_model->load_nyheder()) before loading your view.

Problem with the sql query in your nyheder model maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that problem is probably somewhere in your model...or maybe it's something even more obvious like the database option is not activated...Try:

```
 function __construct(){
          parent::Controller(); 

          $this->load->database();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok going to guess that load_nyheder() is either returning an object or an array
so check the plumbing first by hardcoding and array something a bit like this:

```
$data['query'] = array(
            'keystr1' => 'valuestr1',
            'keystr2' => 'valuestr2',
            'keystr3' => 'valuestr3'
                       );
$this->load->view('nyheder_view', $data);
```

NB: If you put an object as $data it will be converted to an array.

Then in your view "nyheder_view" do something more like this:

```
<?php foreach($query as $someKey=>$someValue):?>
    <h1><?php echo $someKey; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $someValue; ?></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Get it all working with hardcoded test (fixture) data first, then try feeding $data['query'] with your your load_nyheder() and see if you get similar problems. That way you know where the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I think you're missing the result() after $query...

```
<?php foreach($query->result() as $row) : ?>
   <h1><?php echo $row->overskrift; ?></h1>
   <p><?php echo $row->indhold; ?></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: You're just calling result() on an undefined variable, that won't solve anything